# Eclipse Javadoc error/exception

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I am trying to attach the javadoc to Guava in Eclipse. I set the javadoc location to http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/, the validation passes. When I press F2(force show javadoc) on a Guava class, I get the error below. I am I doing something wrong?

eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
java.version=1.6.0_29
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

Error
Thu Oct 27 14:46:53 PDT 2011
String index out of range: -10

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -10
    at java.lang.String.checkBounds(String.java:397)
    at java.lang.String.(String.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getURLContents(JavaElement.java:786)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BinaryType.getJavadocContents(BinaryType.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BinaryType.getAttachedJavadoc(BinaryType.java:995)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.javadoc.JavadocContentAccess2.getHTMLContent(JavadocContentAccess2.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.getHoverInfo(JavadocHover.java:621)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.internalGetHoverInfo(JavadocHover.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.getHoverInfo2(JavadocHover.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaTypeHover.getHoverInfo2(JavaTypeHover.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaInformationProvider.getInformation2(JavaInformationProvider.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.information.InformationPresenter.computeInformation(InformationPresenter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractInformationControlManager.doShowInformation(AbstractInformationControlManager.java:1131)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractInformationControlManager.showInformation(AbstractInformationControlManager.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer.doOperation(SourceViewer.java:941)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.projection.ProjectionViewer.doOperation(ProjectionViewer.java:1534)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaSourceViewer.doOperation(JavaSourceViewer.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor$AdaptedSourceViewer.doOperation(CompilationUnitEditor.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.TextOperationAction$1.run(TextOperationAction.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.TextOperationAction.run(TextOperationAction.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$InformationDispatchAction.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:1904)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.ui.commands.ActionHandler.execute(ActionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerWrapper.execute(LegacyHandlerWrapper.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.executeCommand(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.press(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:786)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.processKeyEvent(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.filterKeySequenceBindings(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.access$3(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1262)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1052)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1100)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmKeyDown(Widget.java:1809)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_KEYDOWN(Control.java:4892)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4560)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4985)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2531)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3752)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by removing the library and adding it back in. I should have done this in the first place, but I spaced it. EDIT: And now it's broken again. I don't know what is happening.